# Laravel does't work in my web host

Tags: laravel

I uploaded my laravel files to my web host and when i'm trying to access the public folder I get error `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Couldn't find any logs in my `storage/logs/` and the folder is writeable.

Any ideas what can cause this error without any logs?

Comment: Check web server logs too.

Comment: Couldn't find any error in my web server logs

Answer (score 0):

Try to give those permissions to your project directories `bootstrap/cache & storage`:

```
chown -R apache:apache storage
chown -R apache:apache bootstrap/cache
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added permission to the boostrap/cache too, but the error 500 remains

Comment: do you get a blank screen?

Comment: Try to add /public to your url

Comment: I have /public in my url. Without public the error is Forbidden 404

Comment: I think your server configuration prevent the laravel `.htaccess` from redirecting. recheck the log.

Comment: In another web host it works. Any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: PHP Version: Php 5.5.36

Comment: Not sure which Laravel version you're running but you should consider that the PHP v5.5.36 will run just Laravel project v4 & v5.0